# how would i reference this code within php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql

the image needs to echo to the page and it cant. $log_username refers to the folder the user is named after . How can i reference this code so that the image displays on the page?

```
 <img src="users/<?php echo $log_username.$main_image;?>/>
```

Comment: What does the interpreted source code look like? Maybe you're only missing a `/`

Comment: So is this a PHP page? If so, show a bit more code... like are you nesting echoes?

Comment: "the image needs to echo to the page and it cant" Can you rephrase the question, show us what `$log_username` and `$main_image` contain, and the HTML you expected to see?

Comment: @Popnoodles . $log_username is the actual users folder name with which i am current logged in as there are different users.I want to echo the image that has been upload into that file, via the moveupload(). the image is within the users file but it just wont show up on the page, all the users other info show up

Comment: People are guessing at the problem because you haven't given enough information and you respond with "doesn't work". Please edit your question providing clarity. It is likely to be closed otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can understand you are missing `/` so it will be like this

```
<img src="user/<?=$log_username. '/' . $main_image;?>"/>
```

Comment: still doesnt work :/ . You think this could be a file permission problem? the image saves into to users folder when i upload it but when i want to view/ echo the image it does not

Comment: Asking if it's a file persmission problem on every answer is not helping us help you. Try clarifiying your question above.

Comment: @Tom Kriek is correct, And try to call the image without using any php like `<img src="users/image.jpg"></img>`

Comment: @roun512 i did and I  receive  the name of the image not the actual image

Comment: Are you sure that there is an image in the sub folder with the same name ?

Comment: yes as i have checked , everything works except being able to view the image.

Comment: Okey Updated it, it should work fine now

Comment: @roun512 OMG DUDE! your Amazinggggggggggggggggggggggggggg.........

Comment: @roun512 You made my day man. Thanks too everyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
<img src="users/<?php echo $log_username.$main_image;?>/>
```

should be:

```
<img src="users/<?php echo $log_username.$main_image;?>" />
```

notice the double quote in the end.

Comment: that doesnt work either. You think this could be a file permission problem? the image saves into to users folder when i upload it  but when i want to view/ echo the image it does not.

Comment: Permissions have to do mostly with writing files, not reading ones. Is this php file in your root and you have a `users/` folder in there, where the image exist? Does the image exist anyway? Perhaps you can't save the image due to writing permissions as well. Also, can you print that `$log_username.$main_image;` to know what looks like?

Comment: yes i have a users folder in there , the  $log_username refers to the users name within the users folder, where the image is, the image is in there

Comment: print_r() for $log_userame prints the users name and print_r() for $main_image prints the actual name of the image i am trying to echo

Comment: So, if `$log_username` is a subfolder and does not ends with `/` you should add one before concatenating like "users/<?php echo $log_username."/".$main_image;?>".

Comment: It would be really helpful if you just print a _sample_ rather than explaining what the variables contains. A sample, just load your file and copy/paste the _<img>_ tag from your page's source in your question preferrably.

Comment: this is my move_result code , when i upload image  }else{$moveResult=move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,"user/$log_username/".$main_image);
       if($moveResult !=true){
       echo " <script>alert('file upload failed , try again') </script> ";
        exit();